# What are these orange flowers?

Tags: identification

I found these in a country park as well.  I'd like to identify them if I can.  While they seem quite distinctive in appearance to me I cannot find them online.

[image: Orange Flower]
[image: Orange Flower from above]

EDIT: 
I had used a link to flickr before SE used imgur.com for hosting images. I think I'd moved the images around in flickr which broke the url.  I couldn't find a way to figure out which images I'd originally got posted in this question.  I picked two.  You can find these and other flower images on my [flickr account](https://www.flickr.com/search/?tag_mode=all&sort=relevance&user_id=92157978%40N06&tags=flower&view_all=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Greigii tulip, possibly the cultivar ["Tulip Girlfriend"](http://www.growingtulips.eu/cat-Tulip-Bulbs-Greigii-105.htm).  They are descended from tulips that grow in Turkestan.  They tend to be shorter than other tulips at around 10 inches.  They are perfect for rock gardens or front of the border and naturalize well.  Full sun to part sun.
The usual animals like them too: rabbits, squirrels.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking online it does look right.  There are so many variations on flowers.  It makes me wonder how people ever decide on how to classify them.